# Two inner joins and preventing duplicate records in query

Tags: ms-access, database-design, inner-join

Here's my scenario. Basically I have a *JobItem* table that is associated with a parent *Job* table. These *JobItem* records contain a **JobID** to associate them to the parent record, a **FunctionCode** specifying a function of work, and a **FunctionCost** specifying a cost which is associated with how much 1 unit of that function would cost.

I have a *TimesheetItem* table that contains information regarding what work the employee did. So if they say they did 50 units of **FunctionCode**, this needs to tie to the **JobItem** where the **JobID** on the *TimesheetItem* matches the **JobID** in the *JobItem* table AND where the **FunctionCode** on the *TimesheetItem* matches the **FunctionCode** on the *JobItem*.

This is so that I can accurately SUM the cost of work by multiplying units the employee completed with the cost per unit (which is on the *JobItem* form).

So I am using an INNER JOIN between the *JobItem* and *TimesheetItem*. Is this OK to do? Is this correct design for this situation?

Hopefully this isn't confusing. Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TimesheetItem.EmployeeID, 
  SUM(JobItem.FunctionCost * TimesheetItem.UnitCompleted) AS TotalCostPerEmployee
FROM (Job
  INNER JOIN JobItem ON Job.ID = JobItem.JobID) 
  INNER JOIN TimesheetItem ON (JobItem.JobID = TimesheetItem.JobID) 
    AND (JobItem.FunctionCode = TimesheetItem.FunctionCode)
GROUP BY TimesheetItem.EmployeeID
```

The above query is an example of how to get total value of work performed per employee.  You will have to replace `TimesheetItem.UnitCompleted` and `TimesheetItem.EmployeeID` with what the actual field names are.

If you prefer to have the totals grouped by `FunctionCode` then the following should work:

```
SELECT TimesheetItem.FunctionCode, 
  SUM(JobItem.FunctionCost * TimesheetItem.UnitCompleted) AS TotalCostPerFunctionCode
FROM (Job
  INNER JOIN JobItem ON Job.ID = JobItem.JobID) 
  INNER JOIN TimesheetItem ON (JobItem.JobID = TimesheetItem.JobID) 
    AND (JobItem.FunctionCode = TimesheetItem.FunctionCode)
GROUP BY TimesheetItem.FunctionCode
```

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much the same structure I had for my query. Now my question is: what if there are two job items with the same JobID and FunctionCode. If an employee has 5 hrs with that same JobID and FunctionCode in their timesheet will it be "double counted" due to the inner join query? So, for example, would it show 10 hrs of work since there are two matches in the JobItem table that match the FunctionCode and JobID specified on their timesheet? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes if you are grouping by the function code then anything with that function code will be included in the value.  The sum of the records is based on how you group them.  So, maybe you are looking for `GROUP BY JobItem.JobID, TimesheetItem.FunctionCode`

Comment: Right. But I did use `GROUP BY JobItem.JobID, TimesheetItem.FunctionCode` and that still gave me a duplicate. This is because I have a job that has two items that both have the same _FunctionCode_ and _JobID_. So when I run my query to SUM timecards grouping by the JobID and FunctionCode, it doubles their time because it the same _FunctionCode_ and _JobID_ shows up twice in the job being referenced. Does that make sense? Would this need to be split out into a separate query?

Comment: So, you are saying then that you do not want to sum based on the FunctionCode/JobID then.  What field do you have in your table that would get you to the proper grouping?  It sounds like you want to group based on the item.  So how about something like `GROUP BY JobItem.ItemId, JobItem.JobID, TimesheetItem.FunctionCode`